# A PHP Github class to do updates only

Tags: php, svn, github

I have a PHP application which i want to extend with self updating capabilities. To me the best solution for this is to use some sort of SVN protocol to update my PHP application.

Currently my application is hosted on Github, so i'm really looking for a class which is able to do update my local application with the latest version on Github.

Is there such a class available? I'd like to have a class which does just that. I don't need functionality to commit code, list files in a repository or things like that. All it needs to do is an update.

So i'm looking for a ***pure*** PHP class which can do this, which doesn't need any Github application to be installed on the machine in order to work.

So something simple like:

```
$repo = new Github ( 'path/to/local/repo', 'url/to/remote/repo', 'master' );
$repo->update ( );
```

Comment: @MarkBaker I can't install any thrid party applications like that. It's also too big for my purposes. All i want is an `Update` command to update my own code from github. Nothing more.

Comment: you can build your own API that does GIT PULL command. can execute shell commands just give it a better UI.

Comment: @GGio But if i'm going to use shell commands then i assume i also need the Git API installed on the machine? If so, then that's not really an option for me since the application is running on alot of client machines. I don't want to bother my clients by asking them to install more software. I was hoping to do something with `curl` if i really have to create something myself.

Comment: http://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/ You could get the tree, then use raw.github.com to get the individual files.  But you'd really be reinventing the wheel.